# Jasperreports excelのシート名を動的に出力したいです

Tags: java

Jaspersoft StudioはProfessional 6.2.0.finalで開発してます。

JasperReportsでExcel(xlsx)を出力時、シート名はDBから取得した商品名にしたいです。
ひと通り調べてみたのですが解決しません。

[イメージ]
MainDataセット.item_name = うどん、ラーメンだった場合

1シート目のシート名：うどん
2シート目のシート名：ラーメン

にしたいです。

Mainレポートのプロパティで下記を見つけました。
先頭のシート名はtokyoになりましたが動的では無いのでこのままではダメです。

property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.names.{arbitrary_name}" value="tokyo"

ご存知の方、教えてください。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://okwave.jp/qa/q9390589.html

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10180915920